# Git Bash indicates wrong branch after performing rebase

Tags: git, git-bash

Recently I had to do a rebase in one of my branches that was successfully done. The conflicts were solved, the branch works as expected and the push was accepted into the remote repo, but after the rebase, git stoped exhibiting the current branch I'm in and always shows the one that was rebased as the current one (as shown in the atached printscreen).

[Git indicating the old branch, even though I already checked out to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnRzX.png)

I can't figure out a way of solving this. I tried some basic stuff like checking out to other branches and pulling the remote, but nothing solved it. Since this is a work computer in which I have almost no permissions, I'd like to try any other solution before resorting to re-installing Git or re-cloning the repo, since I would need to ask someone to do these actions for me.

Comment: The prompt output suggests that the rebase operation is still happening. That's not entirely impossible, you might have pushed "halfway through". As long as you've verified that the remote end has the correct result, you could simply try executing `git rebase --abort` to see if that brings you back into a consistent (though potentially outdated) state. Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you! The ```--abort``` actually worked! And also thanks for the heads up about images, I had no clue, won't happen again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still in the middle of your rebase ("REBASE 6/6"). You haven't completed your rebase. You need to run `git rebase --continue` to continue (and complete) the rebase.

Comment: Thanks! I tried continuing it but since the rebase was "done" from the code perspective and I had no other modification over it I ended up using ```git rebase --abort``` as explained by @joachim in the comments.

Comment: @GustavoTrivelatto `git rebase --abort` will move your `HEAD` to the original state of the branch, `git rebase --continue` will execute any remaining tasks (even if there are no real tasks left).